# Is it possible to use $compile in Angular to create an exportable elem?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to create an elem/string which gets compiled by Angular which I then can send to another part of the application which is outside of angular?

```
var eventListElem = $compile('<full-event-list></full-event-list>')(scope);

myFuncOutsideOfAngular(eventListElem);
```

I have created a directive (full-event-list) which takes an event list from the selected scope and repeats over it and creates my HTML (works in my Angular app).

But when I send the eventListElem to my legacy jQuery part of the application it only renders [Object object] in the DOM. I have tried to do $(eventListElem) and eventListElem.html(), with no luck. Looks like the $compile creates an Angular specific object which I can't convert to a HTML string or a jQuery object.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the resulting HTML supposed to look like?

Comment: <div><ul><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li></ul></div>

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I want/have to support IE9+, FireFox and Chrome.

Comment: Yes, but with what browser are you currently having this issue?

Comment: Chrome and FireFox are tested and don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
var eventListElem = angular.element('<full-event-list></full-event-list>');
$compile(eventListElem)(scope);
scope.$digest();
myFuncOutsideOfAngular(eventListElem);
```

as angular.element() is an alias for jQuery if jQuery is loaded it may work.

Comment: My first test with this solution didn't work. I'll see if I can make a plunker with what I want to achieve.

Comment: Try slipping a digest(); after the $compile(...), this will ensure the link function has been run. See update to post.